# Can one send data fom firebase database to email?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase realtime database that stores information about voters for my android app. Is it possible to send the details of this database eg (vote results) to registered voters? Im using email/password sign-in option.
Thanks already.

Comment: Well the idea I had was to send an email to all people who voted letting them know how the results are. But even if its using notifications to achieve this, I still would not mind. But the communication has to be done to all the registered voters...and in this case, they are registered in firebase

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways, it depends on your architecture, Firebase Firestore won't automatically send any emails, but you can use [Could Functions to execute code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) when you change a document on the database, then use the Cloud Function to send the emails.